# Stop Javascript from running backwards once it finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter, hitcounter

I'm currently working on a `Counter` that shows some stats for my Homepage.
Here's the Script I'm using:

```
$('.count-1, .count-2, .count-3, .count-4').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 5000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

Now I only want to run this animation if the counter comes in the screen ... So I got this Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
        gridTop = windowHeight * -10,
        gridBottom = windowHeight * .9;
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        $('.class').each(function () {
            var thisTop = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
            if (thisTop > gridTop && (thisTop + $(this).height()) < gridBottom) {
                // run this if .class gets in viewpoint
            } else {
                // run this else 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

So I put both of 2 scripts together to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
        gridTop = windowHeight * -10,
        gridBottom = windowHeight * .9;
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        $('.count-1, .count-2, .count-3, .count-4').each(function () {
            var thisTop = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
            if (thisTop > gridTop && (thisTop + $(this).height()) < gridBottom) {
                $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
                    Counter: $(this).text()
                }, {
                    duration: 5000,
                    easing: 'swing',
                    step: function (now) {
                        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                    }
                });
            } else {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Now if I scroll down on my page, the counter starts running when it gets in the screen (which is exakly what I wanted) BUT when the counter finishes, the counter starts to count backwards untill `.count-1`, `.count-2` ... is at `1`. And even if I scroll up and down again ... the counter still stays at `1`. Sometimes the `1` changes to a `2` or `3` but than quickly goes down to a `1` again.

Here's the snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
        gridTop = windowHeight * -10,
        gridBottom = windowHeight * .9;
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        $('.count-1, .count-2, .count-3, .count-4').each(function () {
            var thisTop = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
            if (thisTop > gridTop && (thisTop + $(this).height()) < gridBottom) {
                $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
                    Counter: $(this).text()
                }, {
                    duration: 5000,
                    easing: 'swing',
                    step: function (now) {
                        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                    }
                });
            } else {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
/* just for some scrolling */
#container {
  margin-top: 1000px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Scroll down!</p>
<div id="container">
  <div class="count-1">200</div>
  <div class="count-2">100</div>
  <div class="count-3">50</div>
  <div class="count-4">4</div>
</div>
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Can we get a codepen?

Comment: Yep ... here you go https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eEQjMw I also added a snippet to the question ;)